# Detect if keys are pressed (and count) (not keylogging) in Python

Tags: python, keyboard, keylogger

I was wondering if there's a way to detect onkeyboardevents, but just to count them. I don't want to know exactly what the user has typed, but more like if he typed anything.

To be more specific:
If user presses key "a" on keyboard, I am interested to know that he pressed it (and at what time), not what the letter is.

Scenario:
User types in "hello stackoverflow" in the span of 2.5 seconds. 
I want to know that he was typing something, don't care about what he typed.

Why do I want to do this? Some programs detect "keyloggers" as viruses (and they should) and I don't want my users to think it's something fishy.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

in python keylogger itself, just keep a count in the place of recording the key stroke,

```
while(event.Ascii):
   c++
```

refer: https://github.com/VigneshPrasadV